# Are there affordable and recognised Ubuntu/Debian online certification courses/exams?

Tags: certification

I like Ubuntu (on a server as well as on a client) and Debian and am interested in getting Ubuntu/Debian-related job. So I look forward to get certified to enrich my CV.

But the options I've found in [Canonical eShop](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=21) are too expensive for me, the most interesting one "Deploying Ubuntu Server Edition" even costs £1010.54 - an enormous price for me (it's near my half-year income, as I am a sysadmin freelancer in an East European country).

Are there cheaper ways to get certified? I can hardly invest more than €100 in this, but have got some experience already and supposedly can prepare myself. I'd prefer a 100% on-line way.

Comment: I fear you're out of luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the opportunity to travel to conferences, occasionally [Linux Professional Institute](http://www.lpi.org/) will offer their most basic exam on site, for free.  It is a first step towards full certification. Since the Ubuntu certification is based on the LPI, it may be possible for you to take several exams spread out over time to decrease the impact on your finances.